# Weird exception on createHttpBackend when doing an $http.get

Tags: angularjs

I'm just getting started on AngularJS and for some reason I'm having a problem. I'm running an http get query to the Last.fm API in order to retrieve similar artists to Caravan. I have tried the query on a web browser and it returns the correct XML response.

This is my controller:

```
function ArtistsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    //artist: $scope.artist;
    $scope.getArtists = function() {
        $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=Caravan&api_key=MY_API_KEY').success(function(data) {
            echo(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            echo(data);
        });
    };
};
```

And this is my view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My HTML File</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ArtistsCtrl">
        <button ng-click="getArtists()">Get artists</button>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-resources.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I click on the button and it executes $http.get, it throws the following exception and never returns any data.

```
[Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/AngularJS/angular.js :: createHttpBackend/< :: line 9409"  data: no]
http://localhost/AngularJS/angular.js
Line 5764
```

Anyone has any idea about what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong (except you should probably use the `params` option for your URL parameters). In a Plunker, I get a 403 as expected. If you add your API KEY to this Plunker, does it work? http://plnkr.co/edit/X4bcSlCu2Wh5yzbreyCo?p=preview

Comment: `artist: $scope.artist;` is not a valid JavaScript.

Comment: Yes Josh, works perfectly on plunker. I also tried using on Plunker the getArtists function I used previously, and it works like a charm. I will try redownloading angular.js now.

Comment: Thanks Stewie, but the problem persists.

Comment: Indeed Josh, it works with the redownloaded AngularJS version (1.0.5). It gave me the error using 1.1.3 . Curious.

Comment: I have this issue with angular v1.2.3 and bootstrap js v3.0.0.

Comment: I also have this error :(

Comment: For me the issue was, my site was running on https, but my ajax calls were to an API running on HTTP. If using angular 1.0.5 you get a proper exception 'block mixed active content', but in higher versions you get that weird exception you have. I fixed the issue for me by serving my api under https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried downloading AngularJS 1.0.5 and it worked fine, it gives me the error on 1.1.3 .